# Android: OnClick на элемент который в ListView

Tags: xml, android-sdk, android, listview, java

Из-за того. что ListView height = "match_parent", то в адаптере:

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Log.d(TAG_DEBUG,parent.toString());
         if(convertView == null) {
             Log.d(TAG_DEBUG,"11");
         }else {
             Log.d(TAG_DEBUG,"22");
             button1 = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
             button1.setOnClickListener(mBuyButtonClickListener);
         }
        return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

    }
```

Никогда не срабатывает **else**, и из-за этого, ни одной из кнопок , которые есть в ListView не присваивается **onClick**. По этому не выходит повесить обработчик на кнопки.

Как только **ListView height = wrap_content**, так 1 раз срабатывает, и **onClick**  присваивает только первой кнопке в списке.

Вдруг поможет, **Layout ListView:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:focusable="false">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/list_orders"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
       />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:id="@+id/num_ord"
        android:background="@drawable/fon_ord"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:focusable="false" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:id="@+id/title_ord"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:typeface="serif"
        android:textStyle="normal|italic"
        android:focusable="false" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Сумма:"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:background="@drawable/fon_ord"
        android:focusable="false" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:id="@+id/sum_ord"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="-24dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_marginLeft="64dp"
        android:focusable="false" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Количество:"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:background="@drawable/fon_ord"
        android:focusable="false" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:id="@+id/count_ord"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="-24dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_marginLeft="106dp"
        android:focusable="false" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Дата:"
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:background="@drawable/fon_ord"
        android:focusable="false" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:id="@+id/date_ord"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="-24dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:focusable="false" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="127dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:text="Удалить"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:focusable="false" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="127dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:text="Изменить"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginTop="-37dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:focusable="false" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кнопки в листвью не самое лучшее решение, используйте контекстное меню для вызова дополнительных действий и `SwipeToDismiss` для удаления итема (если это потребуется)

Comment: А каким способом можно в контекстном меню реализовать доп действия ?

Comment: [PopupMenu](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html)

Comment: Понял. Думаете это лучше чем 2 кнопки (Удалить/Править) ?

Comment: Разумеется, будет лучше. Я у себя раньше такую же штуку [реализовал](http://i.imgur.com/OPDyGzL.png).

Comment: Для общего развития:

[10 анти-паттернов навигации в Android][1]

[Ошибки Android интерфейса Evernote][2]

[Ошибки Android интерфейса Twitter][3]


[1]: http://habrahabr.ru/post/213097/
[2]: http://habrahabr.ru/post/215027/
[3]: http://habrahabr.ru/post/216629/

Answer (score 2):

Повесьте обработчик кнопок через лейаут:

```
 <Button style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
     android:onClick="BuyButtonClicked" 
 />
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать так:

```
// Объявление адаптера
//........
LayoutInflater lInflater;
//.......
@Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // используем созданные, но не используемые view
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
      view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
    }
    button1 = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(mBuyButtonClickListener);
    //.......
    return view;
}
```

Взято вот отсюда:
http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/113-urok-54-kastomizatsija-spiska-sozdaem-svoj-adapter.html